# Take two variables and put them on the same line

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script (thanks in largely to this site) that takes names of people from a text file and splits them into FullName, FirstName, LastName and FirstLetter.

I now plan on importing these into AD and largely, I know what I am doing.

However, I am struggling with the following section

```
New-ADUser -Name
```

I would like to do something like this

```
$result.ForEach({
New-ADUser -Name $_.FirstName + $_.LastName -GivenName $_.FirstName -Surname 
$_.LastName -AccountPassword 
(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "APassword!" -Force) 
-PasswordNeverExpires $True -UserPrincipalName 
"$_.FirstLetter+$_.LastName@vennershipley.co.uk"
-SamAccountName "$_.FirstLetter $_.LastName" 
-Path 'OU=Users,OU=London,OU=Sites,DC=MyCompany,DC=local' 
})
```

This returns a error stating 'The name provided is not a properly formed account name'. Now I presume this is because, if I do this

```
$result.FirstName + $result.LastName
```

It returns the 3 first names and the 3 last names on seperate lines, so I would presume it is trying to name each person with a name on two seperate lines like

- FirstName
- LastName

So how would I make the result display on one line, presuming this is the issue?

Also, if there are better ways of doing the AD Creation then please advise, I am still learning!

Comment: Close $result.FirstName and $result.LastName in brackets: ($_.FirstName + $_.LastName)
But the first name and the last Name would be concatenated. If you want to separate them, use it like this: ($_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName)

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the two variables in parentheses to get the results of the addition just like you did in the `ConvertTo-SecureString` part:

```
$result.ForEach({
New-ADUser -Name ($_.FirstName + "" + $_.LastName) -GivenName $_.FirstName -Surname 
$_.LastName -AccountPassword 
(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "APassword!" -Force) 
-PasswordNeverExpires $True -UserPrincipalName 
"$_.FirstLetter+$_.LastName@vennershipley.co.uk"
-SamAccountName "$_.FirstLetter $_.LastName" 
-Path 'OU=Users,OU=London,OU=Sites,DC=MyCompany,DC=local' 
})
```

Now, as you asked for better ways, see few possibilities including [Splatting parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) and [string.format](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/11/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/) `(-f)` Also notice the differents between the string formatting in the `Name` and `SamAccountName` Parameters:

```
foreach ($user in $result)
{
    $Params = @{
    Name = "$($user.FirstName) $($user.LastName)"
    GivenName = $user.FirstName
    Surname = $user.LastName
    AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "APassword!" -Force)
    PasswordNeverExpires = $true
    UserPrincipalName =  "{0}{1}@vennershipley.co.uk" -f $user.FirstName.Chars(0),$_.Lastname
    SamAccountName = "{0}{1}" -f $user.FirstName.Chars(0),$_.Lastname
    Path = 'OU=Users,OU=London,OU=Sites,DC=MyCompany,DC=local'
    }

New-ADUser @Params

}
```

One more thing: to check everything is good just before executing this in production, i suggest you to add the `-WhatIf` parameter to the `New-ADUser` cmdlet, it will demonstrate the operation but will not run it

Comment: This is really helpful. However, I ran this with -Whatif and it gives me the results that look correct. One example being **What if: Performing the operation "New" on target "CN=Jolene Matthew,OU=Users,OU=London,OU=VS Sites,DC=Vennershipley,DC=local".**

But, when I run the actual line, it still errors 

**New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At line:2 char:5
+     New-ADUser -Name ($_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName) -GivenName $_ ...**

Comment: try my version... also post the results of `$result.ForEach({ ($_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName) })`

Comment: Looks to work. The server is unwilling to process the request which is most likely a setting by my boss somewhere so will have a talk with him now. Thank you for you help!

Results for $result.ForEach({ ($_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName)})
Jolene Matthew
Ilka Clune
Emma Bowyer